# Mutating an object in an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, reference, nsmutablearray

I have an object of type `ObjectManager` that has a an `NSMutableArray` properties, lets call it `_objArr`. `_objArr` is full of objects of type `MyObject`. Below is `MyObject`

```
typdef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ObjectStatus)
{
    ObjectStatusZero = 0,
    ObjectStatusOne = 1, 
    ObjectStatusTwo = 2
}

@interface MyObject : NSObject    

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, assign) ObjectStatus status;

@end
```

There are two methods involved in the issue: `userInitiatedMethod` and `timerInitiatedMethod:`. First, `userInitiatedMethod` is called:

```
- (void)userInitiatedMethod
{
    MyObject *obj = _objArr[0];
    obj.date = [NSDate dateWithHoursFromNow:1000];
    obj.status = ObjectStatusTwo;
}
```

Then a few seconds later, the timer fires:

```
- (void)timerInitiatedMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    MyObject *obj = _objArr[0];
    // do stuff with object
}
```

The timer is created in the `ObjectManger`'s `init` method:

```
if (_pruneTimer)
            {
                [_pruneTimer invalidate];
                _pruneTimer = nil;
            }

            PULLog(@"starting pruning timer");
            _pruneTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(p_pruneExpiredObjs)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
```

The timer initiated method removes the object from `_objArr` depending on if `obj.date` has passed, which is how I found the bug. Setting breakpoints in both of the above methods, I verify `userInitiatedMethod` is called first and sets the object correctly. When `timerInitiatedMethod:` is called, I examine my obj. Only `obj.status` is the newly set value, `obj.date` is the original value that it was before the first method changed it. I've verified the memory address of the instance of `MyObject` is the same for both methods. Why would my primitive value be saved correctly, but not a reference to `NSDate`?

Comment: If this is multi-threaded there's a vague chance that you have a race condition.  But it's more likely that you have a simple bug.

Comment: How do you create your timer?

Comment: You try a breakpoint in setDate?

Comment: @Andy updated question. It sounded like a threading issue after I read the first comment, because the timer is calling the method, but breaking when it's called shows we're still on the main thread `com.apple.main-thread`

Comment: I did set a breakpoint in `setDate`. I confirmed it gets set correctly

Comment: You say obj.date is the original value that it was before the first method changed it. Did you arrive at this conclusion by "counting" time or did you actually check that the .date property is still pointing to the original date instance and not the one with 1000 hours later?

Comment: @EarlGrey I stop it in the debugger and inspect date at every point. The last time I check date when it's supposed to be the new value, the value is the original value, and the memory address of date is the same as it was during the first (and all) checks

Comment: I pasted your code into a skeleton project, ran it, and it did not reproduce your error. This leads me to believe that your issue is either environmental in nature (version of Xcode, etc.) or you have a bug in some other code that you didn't share with us.

Comment: Are you sure you have only one `ObjectManager` and thus one object array? Are you sure the `obj` accessed by the two methods is the same object? Given that the array is mutable, could something have removed or inserted the object at index 0? What is the original date and what does `+dateWithHoursFromNow:` return, and is it actually different? Does the implementation of `MyObject` provide an instance variable for the `date` property? Does it provide the setter?

Comment: @Chris - Do you have a custom setter for MyObject's date property?  If so, can you add it's implementation.

Comment: Is dateWithHoursFromNow: a category method? I am not seeing that in the NSDate docs.

Comment: There is only one `ObjectManager` and one array. I've checked the memory address of `obj` and verified it is the same instance. I created a setting for the `date` property only for debugging purposes. All it does is: `_date = date;` just to set the instance variable. `dateWithHoursFromNow:` is part of a category. All it does is convert the argument to number of seconds and creates a date from that.

Comment: I would put you code for your category in your question. That is what is suppose to actually change your date, if I am following your code correctly. I agree with @HotLicks that it is likely a simple bug and that is where I would look first. Good luck.